# Find NaN in list of floats and set previous and next element to NaN

Tags: c#, linq, list, nan

I have a `List<float>` with some `NaN`'s here and there. I want to expand the `NaN` regions by `1`. In other words, if i find a `NaN` element, I want the previous and next elements to become `NaN` as well.

I made some code that works, but it seems to me that it could be much simpler. Any suggestions?

```
List<float> l = new List<float>() { float.NaN, 1, 2, 3, float.NaN, float.NaN, float.NaN, 4, 5, 6, float.NaN, 7, 8, float.NaN, 9 };
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", l));

List<float> ll = l.Select(item => item).ToList(); // clone list

for (int i = 0; i < l.Count; i++)
{
    if (!float.IsNaN(l[i]))
        continue;

    if (i > 0)
        ll[i - 1] = float.NaN;

    ll[i] = float.NaN;

    if (i < l.Count - 1)
        ll[i + 1] = float.NaN;
}

Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", ll));
Console.ReadKey();
```

Output:

```
NaN   1   2   3 NaN NaN NaN   4   5   6 NaN   7   8 NaN   9
NaN NaN   2 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN   5 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

Comment: you don't need `ll[i] = float.NaN;` because its already there.

Comment: `l.Select(item => item).ToList();` could be `l.ToList()` or `new List<float>(l)`

Comment: Indeed. These improvements simplify the code a bit.

Comment: Do you need to copy the list? I realise the current implementation requires it to avoid filling the array to the end, but if you could avoid that, couldn't you just modify the collection in-place instead?

Comment: I could probably first make a list of indexes to the NaN's and then find the locations that should be changed based on that list. This list will probably be shorter than the copied list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Linq to get the indices that need changing and then imperatively update a copy of the list.

```
   var theNewNanIndexes = Enumerable.Range( 0, l.Count )
        .Where( num => float.IsNaN(l[num]))
        .SelectMany( num => new[]{ num - 1, num + 1  } )
        .Where( num => num >= 0 && num < l.Count) ;


ll = new List<float>(l);
theNewNanIndexes.ToList().ForEach( num => ll[num] = float.NaN );
```

Comment: I like this one for readability and brevity. The list copy is not even necessary.

Comment: You can have a variable maring if the SelectMany part is changed to:  .SelectMany(num => Enumerable.Range(num - margin, (margin * 2) + 1))

Answer (score 3):

Here is an implementation  that uses only one select:

```
l.Select((item, index) => index > 0 && float.IsNaN(l[index - 1]) || index < l.Count - 1 && float.IsNaN(l[index + 1]) ? float.NaN : item)
```

Comment: This doesn't work if **last item in the list is a number** - it will not convert `1 2 3` to `NaN 2 NaN`, but `NaN 2 3`. Yet people upvote this *incorrect* answer blindly.

Comment: @Sinatr Unfortunately, you didn't mention this requirement in your question. To replace the first and last item in the list with NaN, you can use modified version of my query:
 `l.Select((item, index) => index == 0 || index == l.Count - 1 || float.IsNaN(l[index - 1]) || float.IsNaN(l[index + 1]) ? float.NaN : item)`

Comment: I am not op. And op mentioned that implicitly (check his input string and wanted result). Your code from previous comment doesn't works either. Feel free to [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/xpmrjK) with it. You can edit your answer to add improved code if you manage to make it working.

Comment: @Sinatr, I'm sorry, but he didn't mention this requirement even implicitly. Last item in the input string is 9 (in original question, not in your answer). And it shoud be replaced with NaN because the previous item in the input list is NaN, not because it is the last item in the list. There is an error in you fiddle. Your code prints source list twice instead of printing query result. Please, checkout [this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/yqrhL4)

Comment: Sorry, I've made a mistake yesterday evening when testing your code. That new version is working with sequence of more than one number at the end correctly. OP did mentioned a sequence of not `NaN`, [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/uDrlaA) is a proof where your first version of code from the answer doesn't work with just 2 numbers at the end. second method (commented) is working correctly, consider to put it into the answer and I'll delete all my <strike>complains</strike> comments ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use another method *to expand `NaN`*. Notice what expanding is *consuming* first and last number in series of numbers:

> x --- NaN
>
> x y --- NaN NaN
>
> x y z --- NaN y NaN
>
> x y z w --- NaN y z NaN
>
> ...

Not ideal but an example (here is [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/RkHf96) to play with):

```
var list = new List<float>() { float.NaN, 1, 2, 3, float.NaN, float.NaN, float.NaN, 4, 5, 6, float.NaN, 7, 8, float.NaN, 9, float.NaN, 10, 11, 12, 13 };
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", list.Select(o => o.ToString().PadLeft(3))));
int counter = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
{
    if(!float.IsNaN(list[i]))
    {
        // increment counter if number and replace first in serie with NaN
        if(counter++ == 0)
            list[i] = float.NaN;
    }
    else
        // serie finished? replace last number in it with NaN
        if(counter != 0)
        {
            list[i - 1] = float.NaN;
            counter = 0; // reset count
        }
}
// special test if last item in list is a number
// serie finished? replace last number in it with NaN
if(counter != 0)
    list[list.Count - 1] = float.NaN;
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", list.Select(o => o.ToString().PadLeft(3))));
```

Output (I added serie of 4 numbers at the end):

```
NaN   1   2   3 NaN NaN NaN   4   5   6 NaN   7   8 NaN   9 NaN  10  11  12  13
NaN NaN   2 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN   5 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN  11  12 NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this one:

```
private bool IsAdjacentNaN(List<float> list, int index)
{
    var beforeNaN = index != 0 && float.IsNaN(list[index - 1]);
    var afterNaN = (index + 1 != list.Count) && float.IsNaN(list[index + 1]);
    return beforeNaN || afterNaN;
}

List<float> l = ...;
var results = l.Select((x,i) => IsAdjacentNaN(l,i) ? float.NaN : x);
```

In this example, the IsAdjacentNaN abstracts the complexity, so your lambda can be simpler.